# Android List Icon in Prefs

Tags: android, dialog, icons, settings

Does anyone know which resource is used for the "show dialog" icon in Android settings?

It's a little down arrow inside a circle - the same icon appears by default in the title bar of the list dialog.

You'd think this would be easy to find but....no:(

Comment: Any chance you have a screenshot of it? I don't see it in my ICS icon collection. Also what version of Android is this from?

Comment: For future reference, this site might help: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Comment: thanks - that site is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the 'more' icon. It can be used by using this code:

```
 @android:drawable/ic_menu_more
```

Hope this is what you wanted!